# HTML cant update element position

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, dom

Im trying to set the position of all the images that appear on my page. I tried to set the position of one image via DOM, but it seems to have no effect. The console is printing out the updating position message, but the image position is not being updated. I can access the image through DOM, as i can update the images width through the use the 'image' element variable. I just cant update its position.

HTML

```
<div *ngIf='this.imagesPerRow'>
  <div *ngFor="let image of images; let i = index; let last = last">
      {{last ? setPosition() : ''}}
    <img id={{i}} [style.width.%]="width" src={{image.src}} alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

TypeScript

```
setPosition() {
  const image: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('1');

  if (image) {
    console.log("Updating position");
    image.style.left = "100px";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css `left` property works only on **positioned** elements as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)

so chaging your style as follows should do it

```css
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```